# Are these two circuit equivelent (the same)?

Tags: circuit-analysis

> Question: Are these two circuit equivelent (the same)?

[image: Is this the same as]
[image]

Comment: Answer: What do you think, and why?

Comment: @TomCarpenter I think so: because L2 and C2 are both connected to the +terminal of L3 (the top side)

Comment: If you are planning on taking an output from a node on this circuit then no, they are not the same.

Comment: @Andyaka When I want to find the current from the source I can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look good and you see that only C3 and L3 have changed position. Connecting wires do not change a circuit.
Now if you need to calculate voltages and currents in such a system then all loop currents are the same in both diagrams.
If we take the -V as reference then the voltage and phase at the node between C3 and L3 is different depending on the values of C3 and L3.